# Java 8 creating map of a map from list of objects

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have a class

```
Class Employee {

    String company;
    String deptId;
    Double salary;

    // other fields
    // constructors
    // setters n getters      
}
```

I then somehow get the List of this class :

```
List<Employee> employees = getAllEmployees();
```

Now i want the output as a map.

```
Map<String, Map<String, Double>> companyVsDeptVsMaxSalary = employees.stream()........
```

So I want to have a `Map` where my key is the company and values as an other `Map`.

Now that other inner `Map` is a `Map` of dept vs maximum salary in that dept.

I can do that using boiler plate code.

But need to explore java 8 for concise n better code. 
I tried collectingAndThen n other things but couldn't get that right.

Appericiate the help. Thanks.

Comment: This is a specific question i feel. It has an input and requires an output. I'll still try to to be more careful on future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking to group by the `company` followed by another grouping by `depthId` and finally, select the maximum salary of the inner grouping.

This can be done via a `groupingBy` and reducing collectors:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Double>> result = 
     employees.stream()
              .collect(groupingBy(Employee::getCompany,
                              groupingBy(Employee::getDeptId,
                                     reducing(0D, Employee::getSalary,
                                             maxBy(comparingDouble(e -> e))))));
```

imports:

```
import java.util.stream.*;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;
import static java.util.function.BinaryOperator.maxBy;
import static java.util.Comparator.*;
```

Answer (score 0):

This could do the trick:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Double>> map =
    employees.stream().collect(
        groupingBy(Employee::getCompany,
            groupingBy(Employee::getDeptId,
                 collectingAndThen(
                     maxBy(comparing(Employee::getSalary)),
                     o -> o.get().getSalary())));
```

The idea of this code snippet is to map your *employees* by *company* first then by *deptId*. Finally we calculate max salary per company and deptId using `Collectors.collectingAndThen` and `Collectors.maxBy` methods.

Comment: Well, can anyone of downvoters provide some feedback?

Comment: Didn't downvote, but anyway wouldn't it better to just do `o -> o.get().getSalary()` ? instead of `o -> o.isPresent() ? o.getSalary() : 0.0` as there will always be at least one item in each group. if the source is empty then you'd never get to that part anyway.

Comment: @Aomine Yes, you're right. Actually the very first version of my answer was doing so.  Reverted it back.

Comment: Just an update collectingAndThen and maxBy are methods of Collectors and not Comparator.

Comment: @DarkKnight Yes, it's just a typo. Fixed it.